# Is it possible to send/receive faxes directly on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, fax

Is it possible to send and receive faxes directly on the iPhone?

The goal is to try to avoid paying an additional 5 or 10 bux a month to use a 3rd party service.  I'm hoping the functionality can be either bought through an app or configured.

Comment: Can't you just use email instead? Same thing as fax, just without the need for analog.

Comment: @Webs there are some e.g financial/legal transactions that need a fax. Although if one end is email is it still valid ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're looking for the iFax app (Unfortunatlly I don't have a link here at work, but if you search for it in the store it should pop up), however I've got the next best thing!

http://www.macnn.com/articles/09/07/20/ifax.iphone.app.released/

Answer (score 3):

Easy to use.  Take a picture and send.  http://www.boomfax.com

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send and receive faxes straight from your iPhone, Popfax- [http://www.popfax.com](http://www.popfax.com/news/article_1692.html) has developed a fully featured mobile fax website, which turns mobile devices into miniature fax machines. It is easy, quick, and it works on the go.